# Jquery function get old value of id (with modal confirm)

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, confirm

I have a problem. my `onclick` link is this.

```html
<a onClick='ConfveAjaxFormPost(this)' id='$idid' adi='$nei'look='nlme' 
   mdl-tit='title here' 
   mdl-p1='text1here' 
   mdl-p2='text2 here' 
   mdl-btn='del' 
   data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalonay'>DEL</a>
```

This goes `ConfveAjaxFormPost(this)` function...

```js
function ConfveAjaxFormPost(alink) {


var ConfveAjaxFormPost_look =  alink.getAttribute('look');      
var ConfveAjaxFormPost_id =  alink.getAttribute('id');  
var ConfveAjaxFormPost_adi = alink.getAttribute('adi');


/*modal win texts*/
var ConfveAjaxFormPost_tit =  alink.getAttribute('mdl-tit');    
var ConfveAjaxFormPost_p1 = alink.getAttribute('mdl-p1');
var ConfveAjaxFormPost_p2 = alink.getAttribute('mdl-p2');
var ConfveAjaxFormPost_btn = alink.getAttribute('mdl-btn');

$('.modal-title').html(ConfveAjaxFormPost_tit);
$('.sorukismi').html(ConfveAjaxFormPost_p1);
$('.sorukismi2').html(ConfveAjaxFormPost_p2);
$('.modal_confirm_butt').html(ConfveAjaxFormPost_btn);


    $(".modal_confirm_butt").click(function () {



    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data().isSubmitted) {return false;}/** duplicate false */


        $.ajax({
                    url:'start.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data: { OnayveAjaxFormPost_look: OnayveAjaxFormPost_look, OnayveAjaxFormPost_id: OnayveAjaxFormPost_id, OnayveAjaxFormPost_adi: OnayveAjaxFormPost_adi},

                    success:function(data){
                        if     (data == 1){}
                        else if(data == 2){}                        
                        else              {}
                    }


              });

    $this.data().isSubmitted = true; 
    return true;              



    });
}
```

I have a few action links on one page. When I clicked a link show modal-confirm, then click `NOT CONFIRM` button, later I am clicking  another action link and CONFIRM it, the function `$.ajax` post before values (send old id and value)

Please help.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In every click event change variable from:

```
var ConfveAjaxFormPost_look =  alink.getAttribute('look');      
var ConfveAjaxFormPost_id =  alink.getAttribute('id');  
var ConfveAjaxFormPost_adi = alink.getAttribute('adi');
```

To (without "var" )

```
ConfveAjaxFormPost_look =  alink.getAttribute('look');      
ConfveAjaxFormPost_id =  alink.getAttribute('id');  
ConfveAjaxFormPost_adi = alink.getAttribute('adi');
```

> I learned this from, [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343450/rakesh-sadhula] thank you,Rakesh ...